# surface gradient of the unit normal vector

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, curvature

I am reading a book that defines a curvature tensor as $\boldsymbol{K} = -\nabla_\pi \boldsymbol{\hat{n}}$ where $\boldsymbol{\hat{n}}$ is the unit normal vector of a surface and

\begin{align*}
\nabla(\cdot) = \nabla_\pi(\cdot) + \boldsymbol{\hat{n}}\dfrac{\partial(\cdot)}{\partial n}
\end{align*}

What are the components of the tensor $\boldsymbol{K}$ and can they be written in terms of curvature $\boldsymbol{\kappa} = \dfrac{\partial \boldsymbol{\hat{t}}}{ds}$ and torsion $\boldsymbol{\tau} = -\dfrac{\partial \boldsymbol{\hat{b}}}{ds}$?

Comment: Which curves are you using for $\kappa$ and $\tau$?

Comment: The tensor $K$ is a type of _surface_ curvature (the [shape operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_surfaces#Shape_operator) of a surface in Euclidean $3$-space). The "curvature" and "torsion" you mention, by contrast, are invariants of a _curve_.